# Node with many product prices

Tags: nodes

I have a node which needs to contain a list of product prices in the following format:

```
Node Title
Node Body

Product 1 URL - Product 1 Price
Product 2 URL - Product 2 Price
Product 3 URL - Product 3 Price
Product 4 URL - Product 4 Price
```

I'm not sure how that list of URL's and prices should be stored in Drupal so that it can be given a relationship with a specific node and displayed within the node.

Do i use taxonomy or make each url/price pair its own node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. Create a group of fields and assign that field collection in content type.

Answer (score 2):

You should use entity references for this. The end result will be that when you view a parent node, the products show up in a block (or panel pane).

1. Set up a parent node content type and add an entity reference field to the products content type.
2. When you create products, reference the parent node.
3. Create a block view and add a contextual filter for content: referenced (or maybe referencing). your entity reference field. ?
4. In that contextual filter's settings, click provide default: content id from url ?
5. Add fields for the products content type and maybe additional filters as needed.

When you place the block in a region, the products will show up if they reference that node.